# How to find minute averages from time series data in python?

Tags: python

I have an array of tuples like so:

```
timeseries_array = [
    (datetime.datetime(2017, 4, 18, 16, 57, 21, 888778), 10),
    (datetime.datetime(2017, 4, 18, 16, 57, 35, 712351), 36),
    (datetime.datetime(2017, 4, 18, 16, 57, 46, 831850), 70),
    (datetime.datetime(2017, 4, 18, 16, 58, 0, 255499), 52),
    (datetime.datetime(2017, 4, 18, 16, 58, 11, 138477), 34),
    (datetime.datetime(2017, 4, 18, 16, 58, 22, 902610), 44),
    (datetime.datetime(2017, 4, 18, 16, 58, 38, 206132), 106),
    (datetime.datetime(2017, 4, 18, 16, 58, 53, 624415), 81),
    (datetime.datetime(2017, 4, 18, 16, 59, 6, 301157), 56),
]
```

Each tuple is a (date, value).

Once we add new data into this array and it is data for a new minute, I'd like to look at the last two minutes and compare their data averages.

So for this example once we've added data for minute 59, I'd like to find the average of the data found within minute 58 and minute 57 and compare the two.

Minute 57 average would be 38.7 and minute 58 average would be 63.4.

Whats the best way to go about this?  Maybe there is a python library that I should be using?

Comment: what do you mean the average? can't exactly add date time objects

Comment: @DmitryPolonskiy, you can average the second value in the tuple.The last two items in the list at position `(,)[1]` are `81` and `56`

Comment: @Jon I didn't realize that's what we were averaging.

Comment: @DmitryPolonskiy Sorry, yes Jon is right, I want to average the data tied to each of the last two minutes.  I've updated the description to make that clearer.

Answer (score 1):

Here is one way to do it:

```
from __future__ import division

def timeseries_averages(timeseries_array):
    unique_minutes = set(m[0].minute for m in timeseries_array)
    for v in unique_minutes:
        print 'The average of the {} minute value is {}'.format(v, sum([m[1] for m in timeseries_array if m[0].minute == v])/len([m[1] for m in timeseries_array if m[0].minute == v]))

The average of the 57 minute value is 38.6666666667
The average of the 58 minute value is 63.4
The average of the 59 minute value is 56.0
```

Answer (score 1):

This is a perfect application for [`itertools.groupby`][1]. As you add values to the list, keep a "high water mark" of minutes you have already seen.  When a new minute value arrives, process only the last parts of the list (indexes greater than the high water mark) using `groupby` to break the list into chunks. Compute whatever you want on each chunk.

```
import datetime
import itertools

timeseries_array = []
timeseries_mark = len(timeseries_array)
last_minute = 57

for new_value in [
    (datetime.datetime(2017, 4, 18, 16, 57, 21, 888778), 10),
    (datetime.datetime(2017, 4, 18, 16, 57, 35, 712351), 36),
    (datetime.datetime(2017, 4, 18, 16, 57, 46, 831850), 70),
    (datetime.datetime(2017, 4, 18, 16, 58, 0, 255499), 52),
    (datetime.datetime(2017, 4, 18, 16, 58, 11, 138477), 34),
    (datetime.datetime(2017, 4, 18, 16, 58, 22, 902610), 44),
    (datetime.datetime(2017, 4, 18, 16, 58, 38, 206132), 106),
    (datetime.datetime(2017, 4, 18, 16, 58, 53, 624415), 81),
    (datetime.datetime(2017, 4, 18, 16, 59, 6, 301157), 56),
    # Minute 00
    (datetime.datetime(2017, 4, 18, 17, 00, 1, 000), 33),
]:

    minute = new_value[0].minute
    if minute != last_minute:
        tail = timeseries_array[timeseries_mark:]
        advance = None
        for m, group in itertools.groupby(tail, key=lambda tpl: tpl[0].minute):
            values = list(group)
            total = sum([tpl[1] for tpl in values])
            avg = total / len(values)
            print("Average at minute {} is {}".format(m, avg))
            if advance is None:
                advance = len(values)

        if advance is None:
            print("Advance is none. Why?")
        else:
            timeseries_mark += advance

        last_minute = minute

    timeseries_array.append(new_value)
```